# Django python requests library send and receive array values through POST

Tags: python, arrays, django, post, python-requests

I am sending a POST request (with indexed array value) in Django (Python 3+) like:

```py
def wordgrpocc_ajax(request):
    woccs= []
    postVars= request.POST

    print('postVars= '+str(postVars))
    # OUTPUT: postVars= <QueryDict: {'syear': ['0'], 'eyear': ['0'], 'word_id[]': ['629c48a694c367c0e07f1d3a', '629c481e94c367c0e07ee8bc', '629c48c694c367c0e07f2864']}>

    url = skpsettings.API_URL+"word/group/occurrence"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    bresplist = requests.post(url= url, data=json.dumps(postVars), headers=headers)
    woccs= bresplist.text

    return HttpResponse(woccs, content_type="application/json")
```

Output of the print in above def:

> postVars= <QueryDict: {
> 'syear': ['0'], 'eyear': ['0'], 'word_id[]':
> ['629c48a694c367c0e07f1d3a', '629c481e94c367c0e07ee8bc',
> '629c48c694c367c0e07f2864']}>

When I catch the request (in *skpsettings.API_URL+"word/group/occurrence"*), the array value is corrupted. Only the last value of the array is received:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def api_WordGroupYearOcc(request):
    wocclist= [{}]
    if request.method == "POST":
        postVars= json.loads(request.body)
        word_ids= postVars.get("word_id")
        #word_ids= request.POST.getlist('word_id', [])
        syear = int(postVars.get("syear", 0))
        eyear = int(postVars.get("eyear", 0))

        print('postVars= '+str(postVars))
        # OUTPUT: postVars= {'syear': '0', 'eyear': '0', 'word_id[]': '629c48c694c367c0e07f2864'}
```

Output of the print in above def:

> postVars= {'syear': '0', 'eyear': '0', 'word_id[]':
> '629c48c694c367c0e07f2864'}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you just want to POST data as is, why parse it? Pass the payload directly as bytes: `data=request.body`

Comment: Nearly same result. This is the output: `postVars= b'{ "syear": "0", "eyear": "0", "word_id[]": "629c48c694c367c0e07f2864"}'`. An extra `b'` is added in the front.